# Plotting multiple curves of Weibull distribution in one graph

Tags: r

I need to plot multiple curves of Weibull distribution having different shape and scale parameters in one graph. I can plot first curve with following code:

```
x=seq(1,15,0.1)
plot(dweibull(x, shape= 3.2, scale=5.6), type="l", col= "red")
```

Now, I want to add other curves with different parameters for shape and scale (for example: shape =2.8 and scale = 6.4) in the same plot. Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: `lines(dweibull(x, shape= 2.8, scale=6.4), type="l", col= "blue")`

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on tidyverse could be:

```
d1 <- tibble(
        Shape=3.2, 
        Scale=5.6, 
        Colour="red", 
        X=seq(1, 15, 0.1), 
        Y=dweibull(X, Shape, Scale)
       )
d2 <- tibble(
        Shape=2.8, 
        Scale=6.4, 
        Colour="blue", 
        X=seq(1, 15, 0.1), 
        Y=dweibull(X, Shape, Scale)
      )

d <- d1 %>% bind_rows(d2)
d %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x=X, y=Y, colour=Colour))
```

[image]

In case it's helpful, an efficient way of plotting *all* compinations of shape and scale could be:

```
d <- tibble() %>% 
       expand(
         Shape=c(3.2, 5.6),
         Scale=c(2.8, 6.4),
         X=seq(1, 15, 0.1)
       ) %>% 
       mutate(
         Y=dweibull(X, Shape, Scale)
       )
d %>% 
  ggplot() + 
    geom_line(aes(x=X, y=Y, linetype=as.factor(Shape), colour=as.factor(Scale)))
```

[image]

This will handle (almost) any number of combinations of `Scale` and `Shape` and the plot can be customised to improve its appearance.